# R: Preserve consecutive numbers in matrix

Tags: r, matrix

In a vector composed of 0 and 1, the '1' should be preserved only if there are at least three consecutive '1'. Here is an example:

```
x=c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0)

x_consecutive=numeric() 
for (i in 1:20)
  x_consecutive[i]=((x[i]>0) & (x[i+1]>0) & (x[i+2]>0)) | ((x[i]>0) & (x[i+1]>0) & (x[i-1]>0)) | ((x[i]>0) & (x[i-1]>0) & (x[i-2]>0)) 

x_consecutive
 [1] NA NA  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0
```

This works quite well for me, but I need to perform this operation for all rows of a matrix like this:

```
matrix(sample(c(0:1),50, replace=T), nrow=5, ncol=10)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    0    1    1    0     1
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    0     0
[3,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    1    1    1     0
[4,]    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1     1
[5,]    0    0    0    1    1    0    1    1    0     0
```

To be transformed into this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0     0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    0     0
[3,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    1    1    1     0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

Is there a some smooth solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `rle` on the logical vector (`x==1`), change the 'values' where the `lengths` is less than 3 and are 1 to 'FALSE', use `inverse.rle` to reconvert it back to the original vector.

```
x1 <- as.integer(inverse.rle(within.list(rle(x==1), 
         values[lengths < 3 & values] <- FALSE)))
x1
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

This can be applied to all the rows of the `matrix` with `apply`

```
t(apply(m1, 1, FUN = function(x) as.integer(inverse.rle(within.list(rle(x==1), 
         values[lengths < 3 & values] <- FALSE)))))
#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0     0
#[2,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    0     0
#[3,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    1    1    1     0
#[4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#[5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

The above code can be also made slightly compact without undermining the efficiency by

```
t(apply(m1, 1, FUN = function(x) inverse.rle(within.list(rle(x),
                 values[lengths < 3] <- 0))))
```

NOTE: Here I am calling `rle` only once and not many times.

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), .Dim = c(5L, 10L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using @akrun's `m1` maybe

```
t(apply(m1,1,function(t) rep(ifelse(rle(t)$lengths>2,1,0),rle(t)$lengths)))
```

Or

```
t(apply(m1,1, function(t) with(rle(t), rep(as.integer(lengths>2),lengths))))
```